# php convert Bytes to nearest MB rounded up

Tags: php, converters

Looking to convert bytes to the nearest MB rounded up.

So..

```
605768 would become 1 not 0.577705
1704342 would become 2 not 1.625387192
```

etc

How do I do this ? I just want the value returned.

Thanks

Comment: What is so difficult ? Divide by 1024*1024 and then [round up](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) o_O ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `round` function, you can receive the expected results. For example

`echo round((605768/(1024 * 1024)));` will produce 1.

Comment: Since the question states "nearest MB rounded up", `ceil()` would be more appropriate since `round()` does rounding in both directions based on the value.

Comment: @j883376 correct, i personally prefer `round` because it provides better configuration.

Answer (score 1):

use **round** function like

```
echo round(0.57705);
```

that means like

```
echo round((605768/(1024 * 1024)));
```

Refer [**THIS**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)